# Solve $2^{99}$ mod $101$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

My number theory is a bit rusty, so i am trying to recall how to work this problem out. 
I know that the euler theorem would state that $2^{\phi(101)} \equiv 1$ mod $101$

But in this case, $\phi(101)$ is $100$ so i only know how to calcuate $2^{100}$ mod $101$

Comment: Can you figure out the residue class $x$ such that $2x\equiv 2^{100}\equiv1\pmod{101}$?

Comment: Ah ha, yes. So i i can see that i can equate  $2*51 \equiv 2^{100}$ mod $101$ thus meaning $2^{1}2^{99} \equiv 2^{100}$ thus $2^{99} \equiv 51$ Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: By Fermat or mod order reduction (1st dupe) $\!\bmod 101\!:\ 2^{99}\equiv \frac{1}2\equiv \frac{102}{2}\equiv 51\,$ by twiddling or mod halving (cf. 2nd dupe).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $$2^9=512 \equiv 7 \pmod {101}$$

So we have that $$2^{99}\equiv 7^{11} \pmod {101}$$

Can you do it now?

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

Answer (score 1):

By Euler's Theorem, we can state that 2^(101) ≡ 1 mod 101. Since (101) = 100, we have 2^100 ≡ 1 mod 101. Then, 2 2^99 ≡ 1 mod 101, which is same with 2 2^99 ≡ -100 mod 101. Since gcd(2,101) = 1, we can divide both side by 2. Therefore, we get 2^99 ≡ -50 mod 101, which is same with 2^99 ≡ 51 mod 101. Therefore, 2^99 ≡ 51 mod 101.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)